# Biblatex apa-style citation link issue

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

The biblatex apa-citation only link the year other than author-year together.

**apa-style:**

[image]

while the citation of a typical **journal paper** looks like this:

[image]

So how to make the default apa-style citation looks like the one above?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[ ]{libertine}
\usepackage[ T1 ]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{DarkBlue}{RGB}{0,51,153}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,%
  linktocpage =true,
  citecolor=DarkBlue,%
  filecolor=red,%
  linkcolor=DarkBlue,%
  urlcolor=green,
} % colorlinks setting


 %----------------------------------------------------------
 %                Biblatex settings
 %----------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  style=apa,
  backend=biber,
  refsection=chapter,
  uniquename=true,
  uniquelist=false,
  maxcitenames=2, 
  natbib=true ]  {biblatex} 
 \DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
 \LetLtxMacro{\cite}{\citet}  % year in ()

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchnameformat{labelname}
  {\ifciteseen}{\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{\value{maxnames}}}{}{}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1 ex }  % bibsep

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\textcite{UL1}\\
\parencite{UL1}\\
\textcite{UL1} \\
\textcite{UL2}\\
\textcite{UL1,UL2}\
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc]

\end{document}
```

**Btw: how to insert MWE once without adding spacing to each line?**

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Your code is not compilable.

Comment: A similar request for the `authoryear-comp` style has been addressed in another post. You should clarify how the last journal citation ("Frost (2005, 2007)") is hyperlinked. Does the text lead you to one entry, or do the active areas "2005" and "2007" point to different entries? If the latter, hyperlinking the closing bracket sensibly is a non-trivial problem.

Comment: Frost (2005, 2007) is hyperliked as: expect for `2007`, the whole link is referred to Frost (2005). BTW, I use texlive 2012 full version under linux.

Comment: So the closing bracket ")" points to the entry for Frost 2005? What about prenotes and postnotes? A screen cap of a few cases isn't enough to specify your requirements. Without these this question is unlikely to get a proper answer.

Comment: As Audrey says, as it stands it's not really clear what the logic _should_ be, so we can't hope to give a good answer.

Comment: The documentation of `apa` says *Refactored hyperref to only link from years to make it consistent across cite commands*.

Comment: @JosephWright I have pretty exactly the same question; I'd like to redefine `\parencite` (and `\parencites` )to use the entire citation (Author, year) as a hyperlink, which would also color it. Is this possible?